# How to response XML with node.js express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, express

I want to response this using node.js and express:

```
<set id="1" state="0" name="wd"/>
```

I tried:

```
xml = require('xml');

res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
res.send(xml('<set id="1" state="0" name="wd"/>'));
```

But in `Wireshark` i see that my response looks:

```
&lt;set id=&quot;1&quot; state=&quot;0&quot; name=&quot;wd&quot;/&gt;
```

How to send my xml correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xml` package converts JS objects to xml (and you are passing a stringified xml). Not what you need. You need to parse the string containing xml to get actual xml data using `libxmljs`.

I would try this:

```
const libxmljs = require("libxmljs");


let stringifiedXml = '<set id="1" state="0" name="wd"/>';
let xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(stringifiedXml);

res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
res.send(xmlDoc);
```

Comment: When i tried to `console.log(xmlDoc)` i got `Document{errors:[]}`. What can i miss?

Comment: I think that `console.log(xmlDoc)` doesnt support `xml` data. Maybe you can try `console.dirxml(xmlDoc)`
https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dirxml_data

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `xml()` function. If you set `Content-type`, the server would send response as xml.

Answer (score 0):

In ExpressJs Simply add the content-type and send a valid XML document as the xmlContent

```
response.type('application/xml')
response.send(xmlContent)
```